# Inline меню в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как добавить inline меню `teams_of_England` в условие `if data == "England":`? Тобеж мне нужно чтоб по нажатию на  `callback_data` равному "England" открывалось новое меню.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["leagues"])
async def football_leagues(message: types.Message):
    football_leagues = [
    (emoji.emojize(":England:") + " Англия, Премьер-лига           ", "England"),
    (emoji.emojize(":England:") + " Англия, Чемпионшип             ", "England-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Spain:") + " Испания, Примера                  ", "Spain"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Spain:") + " Испания, Сегунда                    ", "Spain-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Germany:") + " Германия, Бундеслига           ", "Germany"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Germany:") + " Германия, 2-я Бундеслига    ", "Germany-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Italy:") + " Италия, Серия А                       ", "Italy"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Italy:") + " Италия, Серия B                       ", "Italy-2")
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for league, league_cd in football_leagues:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(league, callback_data=f"prefix:{league_cd}"))
    await message.answer("Лиги:", reply_markup=markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prefix")
async def teams(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    data = callback.data.split(":")[1]
    await callback.answer()
    if data == "England":
        ?
    else:
        await callback.message.answer("Выберите чемпионат Англии")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["teams_of_England"])
async def teams_of_England(message: types.Message):
    teams_of_England = [
    ("Манчестер Сити", "man-city"),
    ("Манчестер Юнайтед", "man-united"),
    ("Ливерпуль", "liverpool")
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams_of_England:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await message.answer("Англия, Премьер-лига:", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Ознакомится с документацией на используемую библиотеку, там есть эта информация

Comment: Так же сделайте клавиатуру как вы делали в начале кода, и отправьте

Comment: @oleksandrigo, то есть также добавить ```dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prefix")```? Но я уже пробовал и не работает, возможно, это потому что получается 2 одинаковых хэндлера